# How to create a whitelist of updatable fields in a CakePHP's model?

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-2.3

I want to create a whitelist of fields that I want to be updatable in CakePHP. I know that I can pass a fieldList array in the call to Model::save(), but this isn't what I'm looking for. What I want is that every model "publish" a list of the valid fields, so if I call the Model::save() method without a fieldList and with data that mustn't be updatable (like the ownerId) this won't be updated.

What can I do to get this behavior? Maybe override the Model::save method in every Model to call at the "original" Model::save with the whitelist? I think this is a good idea, because I don't pollute all the controllers with lots of duplicated whitelists...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This sounds like a use case for a behavior: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html

Comment: Are you sure this must be a behavior? Each whitelist of fields must be different, and this must be done for all the app's models...

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting what you want to achieve. You want to "lock" certain fields from being updated ever? If you don't add a field for it in your forms, the fields won't be updated. If you just want to display the data in your form, just set the field to be disabled, that way the data is shown, but not set in `$this->request->data` and thus not updated.

Comment: @marccasas It's simply meant as another option for you to consider.

Comment: @Oldskool: Exactly, I want to lock some fields from beign updated. But even If I don't add this fields in my forms, a malicious user can send a save order (modifying a "good" form with Firefox Webdevelop or IE developer tools) adding this fields. And this is a big security hole for my app...

Comment: @marccasas Use the SecurityComponent, it will create a unique hash that is partly calculated against the fields in the form. If a user adds/removes fields, the hash will mismatch and the save will be black-holed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, thanks you all for your answers, but I was wrong: I don't need to add this functionality.

The problem I was trying to solve was a security problem, I was trying to avoid form tampering (I've discovered the name just now), and as I am a novice CakePHP user, I didn't know that **CakePHP already manages this problem**.

The answer to my question is very easy: I must use CakePHP's Security Plugin and use the Form Tampering prevention (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#form-tampering-prevention).

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. To whoever finds this: from what I understand, all you have to do to enable the basic tampering protection is add `public $components = array('Security');` to your controller(s). The documentation page is not specific if this is *all* you have to do, but from a quick test I can conclude that adding that just one line works.

Answer (score 0):

Can‘t say I’ve ever needed to do this in CakePHP, but CakePHP only saves the fields you pass it.

If you *really* need to create a white-list and you’re *certain* you only *ever* want these fields saving and *never* any others in your database (although I don’t understand why you have columns for them if you never touch them) then you could emulate this behavior in a model callback method:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $whitelist = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

        foreach ($this->data[$this->alias] as $field => $value) {
            if (!in_array($field, $whitelist)) {
                unset($this->data[$this->alias][$field]);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This will just unset any data not in the `$whitelist` array, but if you really don’t want a column being updated then don’t pass a value for it.

Comment: Martin, it's only for safety. I have fields in my models that shouldn't be updated. As you may know, you can "tweak" a website and add more fields (inputs) or values before sending a form. What I want is to avoid this problem. E.g.: All my models have a companyId field. This field is filled in a beforeUpdate callback in a behavior created by me, and this field shouldn't be updated, never. It's a write-once/read-only field. If I don't protect my models with a whitelist, anyone can add a companyId field in a form, push the send button, and this field is changed... Do you understand me?

Comment: Yes, I understand the use case, and I’m sure we would have all been able to point you in the right direction (in this case, the Security component) had you given the problem, rather than how to implement the solution you had already decided upon (a whitelist of fields) in your original post.

Comment: Martin, you are totally right: my question was completely incorrect. Instead of telling the problem, I was looking for how to implement "my" (wrong) solution. Anyway, thank you for you answer :)